# Shared Preferences Between Activities

Tags: java, android

Still fairly new to android, wondered if anyone can help...

I have an App that has multiple activities.
Each Activity has a shared preferences file to save strings for that activity.
Each preference has its own name.

However, i want any activity to be able to read all preferences....

Am i right in thinking that if i rename them all to the same preference name,
that preference will be accessible from any activity within my App?

Or do i need to create a seperate class to handle all preferences?

Many thanks

Comment: you are absolutely right. It works that way. that's why the prefix shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very good tutorial that answers your questions

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.de/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html